# JS for muti Tabs search. Content shown on click below tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

can anyone advice a JS to achieve something like this? I am doing a search filter, where i have 4 filter groups like (Tab1), (Tab2), (Tab3), (Tab4). I want to show "Tab content" (search filters), after clicking on particular Tab button. For better understanding please see the image below. I found many JS demos for opening one tab and closing other, but I didn't find exactly what I need. I need tabs side by side, and content shown below them so if anyone can help with that, please get back to me. Many thanks

[image]

Comment: Try searching for `horizontal accordion javascript` in google. There are a lot of things out there!

Comment: Hi @Mehran Torki, yes you are right, there is a lot of things out there, but I didn't find anything to achieve this kind of structure.. Tabs on top, content below. I am newbie so I am asking for a help, some solution where I won't have to do a lot of modifications to the code as I am not a programmer nor a profi coder.